# Unity Android list wifi networks and signal strength

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, android-wifi

I'm currently working on a Unity project based on geolocation, and want to use different wifi signal strength to compute the position of an android device, in a known building.

For that, I need to list the available wifi hotspots around the phone, and their own signal strength.

Is it possible natively in C#, or is there something in the assetstore that can do that?

My searchs only leaded me to the way to get the signal strength of the current wifi hotspot the phone is connected to, but not the signals of every hotspots detected...

Comment: I don't think its possible natively in C# when working with Android, but you can refer to the [Android API on WifiManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager).

Comment: I never developped with Android and Unity, so I would like to avoid that if there is another solution...
But I'll start digging how to do that, thank you!